# Transfer Function RLC

Tags: transfer-function, laplace-transform

I would calculate the transfer function of this circuit.

I have the following questions:
I can do the series resistance (R + L) and then make the parallel with the capacitor. 
Finally make the voltage divider with the resistance R).

It would be changing the value of **Vo(s)**?
In this case changing the value, someone could help me solve it?

I also attached a photo of Laplace transformed circuit.

Thank you.

[image: Transformed circuit]

Comment: Your question is  not clear. What do you think is changing the value of \$V_o(s)\$? What starting point do you think it is changing from?

Comment: I am using zero initial conditions.
The value vi(s) is the input value and the value vo (s) is the output.

Comment: OK, then what did you change that you want to know whether it causes a change in \$V_o(s)\$?

Comment: Determine the voltage across the series R/L (or across C), then use the voltage divider rule to find the voltage across L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The series resistor and inductor**
$$Z_{RL} = R_1 + Ls$$
**In parallel with the capacitor**
$$Z_{RLC} = (R_1 + Ls) || (\frac1 {Cs})$$
**The voltage across the RL branch**
$$V_{RL} = (\frac{Z_{RLC}}{Z_{RLC} + R_2})V_i(s)$$

**Taking** \$V_o(s)\$ **as the voltage across the inductor**
$$V_o(s) = (\frac{Ls}{Z_{RL}})V_{RL} = (\frac{Ls}{Z_{RL}})(\frac{Z_{RLC}}{Z_{RLC} + R_2})V_i(s)$$
**Thus, the transfer function is:**
$$H(s) = \frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)} = (\frac{Ls}{Z_{RL}})(\frac{Z_{RLC}}{Z_{RLC} + R_2})$$

Simplify away :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert each component into a Z component, and then treat them like resistors and break it down to simple algebra before re-introducing the components...

Lets call the first resistor R1 and the second R2, than call all of them Z underscore component name... The || means use the resistors in parallel equation or 'X*Y/(X+Y)'...

Z_final = Z_R1 + [(Z_R2+Z_L)||Z_C]

Reintroducing the values, you would have

Z_final = R + [(R2+Ls)||(1/Cs)]

Further algebra would give you the simplest answer.